# Rolling sum function in Rcpp

Tags: r, data.table, rcpp, zoo

I'm working with a large dataframe at the moment and have to create a rolling sum of multiple lengths for a number of variables. I have a working method through `data.table` but it takes quite some time to run through a single variable (roughly 50min per variable).

I've spent some time improving the script to speed it up but have run out of ideas. I have no experience in C++, but thought the `Rcpp` package may be an option. I've looked into it myself but haven't been able to come up with anything usable.

This is my `data.table` script for one variable

```
df_td <- setDT(df_1, key=c("Match","Name"))[,by=.(Match, Name), paste0("Period_", 1:10) 
                                        := mclapply((1:10)*600, function(x) rollsumr(Dist, x, fill = NA))][]
```

I've used `parallel::mclapply` which has helped but it still takes quite a lot of time to work.

```
> dput(head(df_1, 20))
structure(list(Match = c("Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", 
"Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", 
"Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", "Bath_A", 
"Bath_A", "Bath_A"), Name = c("Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono     Lance", 
"Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", 
"Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", 
"Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", "Jono Lance", 
"Jono Lance", "Jono Lance"), Dist = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Dist_HS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Dist_SD = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names =    c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> str(df_1)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   26533771 obs. of  5     variables:
$ Match  : chr  "Bath_A" "Bath_A" "Bath_A" "Bath_A" ...
$ Name   : chr  "Jono Lance" "Jono Lance" "Jono Lance" "Jono Lance"   ...
$ Dist   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Dist_HS: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Dist_SD: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Any suggestions how this could be sped up would be greatly appreciated

Comment: maybe u would like to go back a step or 2 (before you created this huge dataset) if the dataset can be shrunk? maybe there are a lot of zeros in your dataset

Comment: The dataset is created from close to 400 separate files, I've looked at keeping them in list format but it wasn't quicker for me? In terms of the zeros, the data is based off GPS distances with data every 0.1s so there's some zeros at the start of each file but it's different amount for every file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found a solution to my problem [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/run_sum-benchmark/). By adding the following function from `Rcpp`

```
cppFunction('
NumericVector run_sum_v2(NumericVector x, int n) {

        int sz = x.size();

        NumericVector res(sz);

        // sum the values from the beginning of the vector to n 
        res[n-1] = std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end()-sz+n, 0.0);

        // loop through the rest of the vector
        for(int i = n; i < sz; i++) {
        res[i] = res[i-1] + x[i] - x[i-n];
        }

        // pad the first n-1 elements with NA
        std::fill(res.begin(), res.end()-sz+n-1, NA_REAL);

        return res;
        }
        ')
```

The `run_sum_v2` fits into my `data.table` line in place of `zoo:rollsumr` and seems to be a lot quicker (<1min). Need to do some checking on the end data but looks promising so far.

Has taken a 2 plus hour script down to <20seconds so I'm happy with this approach unless there's any issues with it?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are overlapping sums, you can reuse the sums from previous iterations. Here is a possible approach using `shift`

```
library(RcppRoll)
DT[, Period_1 := roll_sumr(Dist, 600L, fill=NA), by=.(ID)]
for (n in 2L:10L) {
    DT[, paste0("Period_", n) := {
            x <- get(paste0("Period_", n-1L))
            shift(x, 600L) + Period_1
        },
        by=.(ID)]
}
```

Using `Reduce` to replace the loop:

```
library(RcppRoll)
DT[, Period_1 := roll_sumr(Dist, 600L, fill=NA), by=.(ID)]
DT[, paste0("Period_", 1L:10L) :=
    Reduce(function(x, y) x + y, shift(Period_1, (1L:9L)*600L), Period_1, accum=TRUE),
    by=.(ID)]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
nsampl <- 6003
nIDs <- 1
DT <- data.table(ID=rep(1:nIDs, each=nsampl), 
    Dist=rnorm(nIDs*nsampl, 1000, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks, however the approach I wrote above outlining building and incorporating a function through `Rcpp` seems to be working well for me. Would be interested to know if it's a good solution from a C++ perspective though as I have no experience in it.

Comment: you might want to time it and see if it fits your needs

Comment: Works very well for me, under a minute for any analysis I had run so far. Big improvement!